Does getting over 100% chance of Rare Boons have any effect?
During a run of Hades II, I managed to get over a 100% chance of Boons being Rare or better by combing the Excellence Arcana card (+50%) with Chaos's Doomed Favor (+56%). Later in the run Chaos offered Hobbled Favor (+81%), which would increase my chance to a total of +187%.
Does going over 100% chance for Boons to be Rare or better have any effect? For example, would it make it more likely to get Epic Boons?


Getting more than a 100% chance of getting Rare or better won't have any more beneficial effect than making sure anything you get won't be a common boon anymore. Even if you got 200%, it wouldn't ensure getting Epic rarity instead, so picking it up wouldn't help you on your run.
It is worth noting that Excellence and Chaos' favors do not work the same way. Excellence can still draw a Common boon, but instead transform it into a Rare one, while Chaos' favors will directly affect the odds of getting a Rare or better rarity boon instead of a Common one. So in the case you gave as an example, you would get 50% odds of getting a Common boon increased to a Rare version, and 137% odds of getting a Rare or better boon (canceling the effect of Excellence in that case).
